# Is there any way to change the value of an ARG in Dockerfile by an if statement?

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, sh

I am facing a blocker while I am trying to change the value of an ARG by an if statement.

This my sample dockerfile:

```
#ABC is an ubuntu based docker image
From ABC 

#sampleArgOne is a build argument it can be contained different values
ARG sampleArgOne="1.2.3"

ARG sampleArgTwo

RUN if [ ${sampleArgOne} = "1.2.3" ]; 
    then \
        ${sampleArgTwo}="sampleValue1"; \
    elif [ ${sampleArgOne} = "5.6.7" ]; 
    then \
        ${sampleArgTwo}="sampleValue2"; \
    fi
```

Error which I got in build of the docker image :

`/bin/sh: 1: =sampleValue1: not found`

My question:
Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_, when you are not using bash?

Comment: You can't change an `ARG` value at all, only accept what's passed from the command line.  An `ENV` setting will hide an `ARG`, and the environment within a single `RUN` instruction will override that, but the environment gets reset at the end of each `RUN` command; that makes this sort of setup tricky, and it'd be better to pass the right `--build-arg` value rather than compute it in the Dockerfile.  I've linked this to a very similar question asking essentially the same thing about `ENV` with some other workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to change the value of an ARG in Dockerfile by an if statement?

No.

By executing `RUN` you are executing a temporary shell. In that temporary shell process, you can change the shell variable that can have the same name as ARG parameters.

Comment: That's the little key that I was missing.  I sensed that there was a scoping issue here and this explains what I was seeing.  Thanks!